# Scala - Count the number of occurrences of every key in an Iterator

Tags: scala, iterator

I have an iterator containing some key value pairs.
e.g

> (jen,xyz) (ken, zxy) (jen,asd) (ken, asdf)

The results should be

> (jen,2) (ken, 2)

How do I use the count function (or any other) to count the number of occurrences of each key in the iterator of that particular collection.

**Edit:**
The collection that this iterator represend in my use-case has a large number of records, possibly in the range of millions, no I need the most efficient (less time complexity) way to do this. I found out that the default **count** method was a pretty fast, and that it could be somehow used to produce the desire result.

Answer (score 11):

The approach that Peter Neyens suggests will work, but it could be very inefficient (time and memory) for some applications due to the way `toList`, `groupBy`, and `length` are used. It is generally going to be much more efficient to aggregate the counts directly into a map and avoid all the unnecessary creation of `Lists`.

```
import scala.collection.TraversableOnce
import scala.collection.mutable.HashMap

def counts[T](xs: TraversableOnce[T]): Map[T, Int] = {
  xs.foldLeft(HashMap.empty[T, Int].withDefaultValue(0))((acc, x) => { acc(x) += 1; acc}).toMap
}
```

Once you have defined the `counts` method you can apply it to your iterator of key-value pairs like so:

```
val iter: Iterator[(String, String)] = ???
val keyCounts = counts(iter.map(_._1))
```

The `counts` method defined above works well for `Iterators` over a large number of values, e.g.

```
val iter = Iterator.range(0, 100000000).map(i => (i % 1931, i))
val countMap = counts(iter.map(_._1))
// Map(645 -> 51787, 892 -> 51787, 69 -> 51787, 1322 -> 51786, ...)
```

works fine, while the approach suggested in Peter's answer, i.e.

```
val iter = Iterator.range(0, 100000000).map(i => (i % 1931, i))
val countMap = iter.toList.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.length).toMap
```

chugs away for a while and ultimately results in an `OutOfMemoryError`. The reason it fails is because of all the unnecessary `List` creation.

Comment: Hey, what's with the unnecessary map? How about an extension method `countBy(f: A => K)`?

Comment: My understanding was the the OP was not interested in the value, he was only interested in counting the number of times each key was encountered. So the map is there only the toss out the value in each key-value pair. A `countBy` would be a nice generalization, but I think you'd still need to do a `map` before the `countBy` for the OP's application.

Comment: @JasonLenderman You are right, I am only concerned with counting the number of times each key is encountered, irrespective of the value contained in those keys.

Answer (score 5):

You can `groupBy` the key and then count the occurrences per key :

```
val iterator = 
  Iterator(("jen","xyz"), ("ken","zxy"), ("jen","asd"), ("ken", "asdf"))

iterator.toList.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.length).toList
// List[(String, Int)] = List((jen,2), (ken,2))
```

Comment: Peter, see my answer below. Using `groupBy` to get lists and then counting each of those lists by `length` is going to be pretty inefficient.

Comment: @JasonLenderman, "pretty inefficient"?  It almost certainly won't make a difference for the vast, vast majority of cases.  Micro-optimizations are just silly until you *really* need them (which is very rare).  **Plus**, if you were *really* concerned about that tiny, tiny bit of efficiency, you should probably rewrite *your* answer to not use a `foldLeft`; after all, a `while` loop is always going to be much more efficient...

Comment: @dhg, the `groupBy` approach is creating a new `List` for every key and each of these `Lists` are instantiated in memory. Also, an additional traversal for each list is required to compute the length. If the number of distinct keys being iterated over (and the number of times they occur) are small then this is probably not a big issue, but it could be *really bad* for some applications. As for using a while loop, I didn't not do that because I consider that a micro-optimization. Why? Because it will only result in a *constant factor* improvement *regardless* of the application or data.

Comment: I agree being aware of intermediate collections is important. After all, how many people are actually named Ken? I've known a few Jens, but that moment is probably past.

Comment: @JasonLenderman No, I think OP doesn't care about xyz, just the counts as you have it. OP's next post will to count keys with values of a given length.

Comment: @som-snytt, it's not entirely clear. I posted a new solution which takes into account the values (the number of distinct values per key.) But my old solution would make more sense if the values of the key-value pairs were really irrelevant.

Comment: @som-snytt, I think you're right. I'm retracting my retraction. My new answer was really equivalent to the old one in any case. I don't think using the `foldLeft` with the `HashMap` is an unreasonable amount of additional complexity for the scalability it buys. In any case, it is good to see a spectrum of solutions.