# Not able to complete the scala Program to count the employee in each country

Tags: scala

I am doing some basic programs in scala

```
import scala.io.Source
/* records.txt
USA,Surender
USA,Raja
CHINA,Yen
CHINA,Chen
INDIA,Adam
INDIA,Edward
```

*/

```
object ReadingFile 
{
def main (args :Array[String]){
val fileLoc = "D:\\inputfiles\\records.txt"
val lines = Source.fromFile(fileLoc).getLines().toList
val linesSplit = lines.map(x => x.split(","))
val linesMap = linesSplit.map(x => (x(0),x(1)))


 }

}
```

I don't know how to use AGG function to linesMap. What do I need to add in my code to get the below output

```
USA,2
CHINA,2
INDIA,2
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scala - Count the number of occurrences of every key in an Iterator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33335040/scala-count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-every-key-in-an-iterator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Source.fromFile(fileLoc)
      .getLines()
      .map(_.split(",")).
      .groupBy(_(0))
      .map(i => (i._1, i._2.size))
```

also can use `mapValues`:

```
Source.fromFile(fileLoc)
      .getLines()
      .map(_.split(","))
      .groupBy(_(0))
      .mapValues(_.size)
```

Comment: Replace last `map` with `mapValues`

Comment: Don't think you need the `.toList`

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul, Yes we can just use the `iterator`